# Google Cloud Platform can't perform action

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Very strange but very annoying error on Google Cloud Platform when I try and import and SQL dump.

> Error
>
> You can't perform this action because we couldn't verify that you have accepted the required Terms of Service agreements. Please refresh your browser window and check that you are logged in with the correct Google Account to avoid this error.

There is no option for me to accept a terms of service. Any ideas? When I go to my IAP in the admin panel it also throws an error.

Comment: I get the same issue at the moment. Can't stop instances of my apps, which is very annoying as well since I am paying for their uptime...

Comment: If you check network requests, there is a failing one with this information: code: 3, errorSpace: "generic", message: "backend error", status: 400 - so it looks like a server-side issue. There is an option to send feedback on that page - the more people use it, the merrier.

Comment: ...aaaand it's fixed now.

Comment: I'd like 10 days extra free trial and £50 credits please 

Answer (score 0):

If something goes strange with GCP services I'd recommend you to check [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/):

> This page provides status information on the services that are part of
> Google Cloud Platform. Check back here to view the current status of
> the services listed below. If you are experiencing an issue not listed
> here, please [contact Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/). Learn more about what's posted on
> the dashboard in [this FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/dashboard). For additional information on these
> services, please visit [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/).

then, as it suggested above, you can contact with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/), even if you don't have a subscription you can report an issue.

In addition, you can file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) or [request new features](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

If nothing helped, you can reach [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

In this particular case it was an issue at the Google's side.